# Outputting all values of an large tensor in Tensorflow.js

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, output, tensor, tensorflow.js

I have an `[174,48]` dimensional tensor and I would like to output **all** (without them being compressed in a manner similar to [this](https://ibb.co/Jm2LW59) values of it into the developer console present in the browser. How would I be able to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example**

```js
const tensor = tf.tensor([[1, 2], [3, 4]]);

console.log(JSON.stringify(tensor.arraySync())); // [[1,2],[3,4]]
```

[`tensor.arraySync()`](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#tf.Tensor.arraySync) creates a nested array of the tensor. [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) is then used to turn the arrays into a string before being printed to the console.

**Alternatives**

Alternatively, you can use [`tensor.dataSync()`](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#tf.Tensor.dataSync), which returns the data in a single dimension instead of a nested array.

Both functions also have a asynchronous version that do not block the UI which is especially useful for large tensors:

- [`tensor.array()`](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#tf.Tensor.array)
- [`tensor.data()`](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#tf.Tensor.data)